# How to add a line break every 3 times in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

In a weather widget I have this for loop for an hourly forecast, but I need it split into 4 lines of 3 instead of a single line with 12 items, how do I add a line break every 3rd time? Here is my for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i<12; i++) {
    document.getElementById("Hicon" + i).style.left = 1.4 +  8.333*i + "%";
    document.getElementById("Hpop" + i).style.left = 2.5 +  8.333*i + "%";
    document.getElementById("Hour" + i).style.left = 1.57 +  8.333*i + "%";
    document.getElementById("Htemp" + i).style.left = 1.3 +  8.333*i + "%";
}
```

Here is my css for Hicon, the css for the other 3 elements are much the same:

```
#Hicon0, #Hicon1, #Hicon2, #Hicon3, #Hicon4, #Hicon5, #Hicon6, #Hicon7, #Hicon8, #Hicon9, #Hicon10, #Hicon11 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 1.4%; /* set in main.js */
    width: 5.5%;
    height: 40%;
}
```

Here is HTML for the Hicon, other items are the same format inside the hourlyforecast div.

```
    <div id="hourlyforecastContainer" class="scaleZero">
        <div id="hourlyforecast">
            <div id="hourlyforecastBG"></div>
            <img id="Hicon0" src="Icon Sets/blank.png"/>
            <img id="Hicon1" src="Icon Sets/blank.png"/>
            <img id="Hicon2" src="Icon Sets/blank.png"/>
            <img id="Hicon3" src="Icon Sets/blank.png"/>
            <img id="Hicon4" src="Icon Sets/blank.png"/>
            <img id="Hicon5" src="Icon Sets/blank.png"/>
            <img id="Hicon6" src="Icon Sets/blank.png"/>
            <img id="Hicon7" src="Icon Sets/blank.png"/>
            <img id="Hicon8" src="Icon Sets/blank.png"/>
            <img id="Hicon9" src="Icon Sets/blank.png"/>
            <img id="Hicon10" src="Icon Sets/blank.png"/>
            <img id="Hicon11" src="Icon Sets/blank.png"/>
```

Comment: If you've separate CSS for all the items, get rid of the absolute positioning, and set `display: block` and suitable `margin` to create "new-lines" for them, except the last-one. If you need some absolute positioning, create a wrapper and position that absolutely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add condition using **[Remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())** :

```
if ( i%3 == 0 )
{
   //Break here
}
```

The condition will be achieved 4 times when `i = [0,3,6,9]`.

You can also use `(i%3==2)` based on **@Tony Wu** suggestion, so the condition will be achieved 4 times also but when `i = [2,5,8,11]`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about `(i%3==2)` if for-loop starts from 0? : )

Comment: What is the correct code for the line break, this doesn't work:     document.write("<br>");

Comment: Thanks  @TonyWu for your suggestion, check my updated answer.

Comment: @Nicoll please provide your HTML so we can see what you mean by doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Zakaria, I added the HTML to post 1, not all as it is very long.

Comment: Based on your code @Nicoll the display should be like following **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1jmL980/)**, check please if that true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96279/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-nicoll).

Answer (score 1):

```
if(i % 3 == 0) {do your thing}
```